# Explicitly run Gradle DefaultTasks in addition to another task

Tags: gradle

I have some defaultTasks specified in my build.gradle. For the purposes of CI I want to be able to run these tasks in addition to some other tasks.

Is it possible to invoke gradle to run the default tasks in addition to some other tasks (without explicitly specific all tasks that are part of "default tasks").

For example:

In build.gradle:

```
defaultTasks 'A','C','D'
```

In my CI i want to run specified default tasks plus task 'E'

So something like:

```
gradle defaultTasks E
```

I want to avoid having to explicitly list all the tasks again like:

```
gradle A C D E
```

Possible ?  (with a single gradle invocation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a new task, called `runDefaultTasks` and make it dependent on any tasks you wish to run by default. Something like this:

```
def defaultTasks = ['A','B','C']

task runDefaultTasks(dependsOn: defaultTasks) {

}
```

And then just call it as follows:

```
gradle runDefaultTasks E
```

Comment: A bit hacky ... but it seems like it's the best solution.